# Are 接続詞 a syntactically unified class or classes of words, and what are the rules governing them?

Tags: grammar, syntax, phrases, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

A recent comment under a question of mine prompted me to consider how 接続助詞 work syntactically, and to discover that different ones follow different 形 ([Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E#%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E) has a nice list). However, no such classification seems to exist for 接続詞, which leads to the question: How do 接続詞 work syntactically?

Most commonly, they seem to exist at the start of clauses, such as

> 後半戦で必死の追い上げを見せた。しかし、あと一歩及ばなかった。

however, some also seem to be joining NPs

> 山間部では雨、または、雪が降るでしょう。

> 身分証明書および印鑑をご持参ください。

Since Japanese Wikipedia classifies these particular 接続詞 as 並立, it would be tempting to draw the analogy that these, similar to 並立助詞, connect NPs while others begin/connect clauses, but this is probably a simplification.

Thus: What are the types of 接続詞, and how can they be used syntactically?

Comment: Wikipedia’s entry for [接続詞](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/接続詞#日本語の接続詞) has a similar list. Isn’t it what you are looking for?

Comment: @aguijonazo It does, but if I'm not blind, it doesn't tell me what they attach to (and thus how they are syntactically treated), no?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about those categorized as 並列, or about 接続詞 in general?

Comment: @aguijonazo I'm asking about 接続詞 in general, though partial answers are also helpful of course!

Comment: I'm imagining a classification scheme something like "all of these 接続詞 (insert list here) behave syntactically like 並列助詞, connecting two NPs, all of these 接続詞 (insert list here) may only go at the beginning of clauses or after the 終止形, all of these 接続詞 (insert list here) may only go after the 連体形 and syntactically act as nouns, etc. (whichever of these actually exist, of course)

Comment: I don’t think there is much syntax to discuss. The only question seems to be what two things they connect, and it will be hard to create exhaustive lists.